# How to parse only specific objects without deserializing the whole JSON file?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a huge JSON file (tens of thousand of objects, >100 MB file) I'm trying to parse in order to extract specific objects. Since the file is this big I'm trying to deserialize only the specific part I need (if it's possible, that is) without having to deserialize the whole file.

Said object should be found based on the the value of a specific property `"arena_id":xxxxx` contained in every object, objects that are formatted like this (stripped down version):

```
{"object":"card","id":"61a908e8-6952-46c0-94ec-3962b7a4caef","oracle_id":"e70f5520-1b9c-4351-8484-30f0dc692e01","multiverse_ids":[460007],"mtgo_id":71000,"arena_id":69421}
```

In order to deserialize the whole file I wrote the following code:

```
public static RootObject GetCardFromBulkScryfall()
    {
        string s = null;

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(GetAppDataPath(), @"scryfall-default-cards.json")))
        {
            s = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

            RootObject card = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(s);


        return card;
    }
```

I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible but in case it wasn't my question is what's the best approach to handling a file this big without having to deserialize it whole.

Comment: take a look at [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJsonWithJsonTextReader.htm) - it will allow you to read the JSON token by token instead of the entire huge file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [JsonTextReader](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) with [JsonTextWriter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) to enumerate objects then deserialize them if their property has needed value.

This code takes 16MB of memory working with 112MB JSON file on my PC.

Let me know if you have questions or need fixes.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string jsonFilePath = "1.json";

                string propName = "arena_id";

                RootObject[] objects = SearchObjectsWithProperty<RootObject, int>(jsonFilePath, propName, 69421, CancellationToken.None).ToArray();

                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<T> SearchObjectsWithProperty<T, V>(string jsonFilePath, string propName, V propValue, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where V : IEquatable<V>
        {
            using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(jsonFilePath))
            {
                using (JsonTextReader jr = new JsonTextReader(tr))
                {
                    StringBuilder currentObjectJson = new StringBuilder();

                    while (jr.Read())
                    {
                        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();                        

                        if (jr.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
                        {
                            currentObjectJson.Clear();

                            using (TextWriter tw = new StringWriter(currentObjectJson))
                            {
                                using (JsonTextWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(tw))
                                {
                                    jw.WriteToken(jr);

                                    string currObjJson = currentObjectJson.ToString();

                                    JObject obj = JObject.Parse(currObjJson);

                                    if (obj[propName].ToObject<V>().Equals(propValue))
                                        yield return obj.ToObject<T>();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string oracle_id { get; set; }
        public int[] multiverse_ids { get; set; }
        public int mtgo_id { get; set; }
        public int arena_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't compile for me (program does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point).

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2017/12/08/async-main-is-available-but-hidden/ Also I re-read you requirements and see current code only searches property value, not object with specific property value, copy current code if it useful for you and let me try to rewrite for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not care about memory, but speed, there is a quick and simple parser translated from C++ as answer to my 1st question, but it has tree like output and it is missing any features except printing and debug/browse object (VisualNode3).

[Way to read (or edit) big JSON from / to stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372425/way-to-read-or-edit-big-json-from-to-stream/55499454#55499454)

Comment: One JsonNode object has around 56B only.