# How would I deserialize a JSON String when i dont require every value?

Tags: c#, json

### Scenario

I am creating a small stateless API type thing which pulls information from a single API, takes only the relevant data, Takes the data and uses it as a search term within the second API. From here I then want to take only relevant information and return it to the user.

### The Issue

The JSON is returned with many values within a single array(most of which are not required) and from my understanding, I need to deserialize the string into individual objects so I can then do a `.Count` to find out the number of cards which have been returned.

### JSON String

The JSON String is large so I will just leave this link in case anyone is interested.
https://api.pokemontcg.io/v1/cards?name=POKEMONNAME

### Values I am looking for

- Name
- SpriteURL
- Types
- Artist

What I have already Tried

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PokemonTCGApi>(data); 

List<PokemonTCGApi> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PokemonTCGApi>>(data);

PokemonTCGApi[] objList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Order[]>(orderJson);

var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

List<JSONClass.Card> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONClass.Card>>(data);
```

### PokeTCG Model

```
    public class PokemonTCGApi
    {
        public string cardName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string Types { get; set; }
        public string Artist { get; set; }

        public PokemonTCGApi(string cardName, string imageUrl, string types, string artist)
        {
            this.cardName = cardName;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            Types = types;
            Artist = artist;
        }

        public PokemonTCGApi(string cardName)
        {
            this.cardName = cardName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please include the models (PokemonTCGApi etc.) in the question as well?

Comment: Well i got it working with a single value utilising quickType and JSONtoC# but that class is far too big for here, ill edit the original model in now .

Comment: Json.NET not requires to have all properties to deserealize json string. You just receive response (probably like json string) and deserealize it into something like `List<JSONClass.Card> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JSONClass.Card>>(data);` where `data` is json string

Comment: What about stream reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55372425/way-to-read-or-edit-big-json-from-to-stream

Comment: You don't have to deserialize all properties.  All omited properties in your class declaration will be ignored. Or go only for the token you need https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

Comment: @Tom, Yes. I was looking for this exact post of yours. I knew I had something about "Reading big Json and Stream".

Comment: And you don't have to make complexe thing or use Json2c#. there is an avaidable SDK with all class method and etc https://github.com/PokemonTCG/pokemon-tcg-sdk-csharp. A simple import and 3 lines and you are good to go.

Comment: @xdtTransform Yeahh downloaded that, quite new to all this stuff so it was beyond confused with the number of classes and structs and everything

Comment: And for your error You are missing a Root object that has a property named "cards" that is a List/array of your `PokemonTCGApi`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't require every value from json string then create to class object what ever response you needed from deserialize, and do like that.

```
 var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeViewModel>>(json_array_string);

var data1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeViewModel>(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize to a List and take only the relevant bits from there.

```
var myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Is ExpandoObject, just my 4 variable class? if so i still get the same error.
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PokeAppMVC.Models.PokemonTCGApi]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: You need to iterate through `myData` and build the `List<PokemonTCGApi>` yourself.